# Text dives under another div

Tags: html, css

I have an CSS issue. My text dives under another div, and I can't find out why. When opening in inspector, I also see the div with just text (named activebox) clutters to other CSS. The div should just be around the text, not around the whole first section. Of course I have looked at 'Similar Questions' first, and I did not find the answer. Where did I go wrong? My full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST PAGE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://gdaygday.com/skin/clean-jplayer-skin/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdaygday.com/skin/clean-jplayer-skin/js/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdaygday.com/skin/clean-jplayer-skin/js/jplayer.cleanskin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).find('.webPlayer').each(function() { $('#'+this.id).videoPlayer(); });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body><div id="wrap">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div id="uniquePlayer-6" class="webPlayer light audioPlayer">
      <div id="uniqueContainer-5" class="videoPlayer"></div>
      <div style="display:none;" class="playerData"> {
        "name": "FavoriteFM LIVE",
        "autoplay": "true",
        "size": {
        "width": "600px" },
        "media": {
        "mp3": "http://media.xseu.net/FavoriteFM"
        }
        } </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

      <div class="Head">
        <h1>Dit is CHX.</h1></div>
      <div class="underscore"><h5>Je neemt ons overal mee.</h5></div>
      <div id="section1">
        <div class="tile1"><div class="tile1title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="tile2"><div class="tile2title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="tile3"><div class="tile3title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="tile4"><div class="tile4title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="tile5"><div class="tile5title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
      </div>

      <div id="activebox">test</div>


      <div class="NieuwHead">  <h1>Nieuw op CHX</h1></div>
      <div class="underscore"><h5>De nieuwste muziek.</h5></div>
      <div class="Nieuw">
        <div class="track1"><div class="track1title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="track2"><div class="track2title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="track3"><div class="track3title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
        <div class="track4"><div class="track4title">Jess Glynne + Tinie Tempah <br> Not Letting Go</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
  background:url(img/bg.jpg);
  height:100%;
}
.logo { 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#wrap {     
  position:relative;
  top: -10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 810px;
  height:100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display:block;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family:Verdana;
}
h5 {
  color: white;
  font-family:Verdana;
}
.underscore {
  position:relative;
  top:-15px;
  text-align:center;
}
#main {
  float: left;
  background:orange;

}
.Nieuw {
  float: left;
  max-width:1040px;
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
.Head {
  max-width:1040px;
}

.NieuwHead {
  max-width:1040px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top:10px;
}

.divider {
  max-width:1040px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top:10px;
}

.activebox1 {
  display: block;
}


.nieuwcontent {
  float: left;
  max-width:1040px;
  top:-10px;
  position:relative;
}

.track1 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.track1title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.track2 {
  position:relative;
  left: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.track2title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}

.track3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.track3title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.track4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.track4title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}

.tile1 {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tile1title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.tile2 {
  position:relative;
  left: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tile2title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}

.tile3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tile3title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.tile4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 240px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tile4title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.tile5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.tile5title {
  top:150px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}


.Head {
  text-align:center;
}


.webPlayer { display: block; position: relative; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Verdana, sans-serif; clear: both; margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.4; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; /* Chrome FIX for full screen */ }
.webPlayer a.smooth { transition: all 0.1s linear; -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear; -o-transition: all 0.1s linear; }
.webPlayer.jp-video-full > .controls { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 1000; }
.webPlayer.jp-video-full, .webPlayer.jp-video-full object, .webPlayer.jp-video-full video { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; display: block; z-index: 999; }
.webPlayer.jp-video-full > .playerScreen, .webPlayer.jp-video-full > .playerScreen > .video-play { z-index: 1000; }
.webPlayer .playerScreen { cursor: pointer; }
.webPlayer .playerScreen .video-play { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 990; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50px; background: url("preimg.png") no-repeat center center; opacity: 0.4; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
.webPlayer .controls { display: block; position: relative; height: 40px; color: #969696; padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 996; }
.webPlayer .controls .leftblock { position: absolute; left: 3px; width: 50px; }
.webPlayer .controls .leftblock .play { display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: url("playerUI.png") no-repeat 0 1px; opacity: 0.8; }
.webPlayer .controls .leftblock .play:hover { opacity: 1; }
.webPlayer .controls .leftblock .pause { display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: url("playerUI.png") no-repeat -40px 1px; opacity: 0.8; }
.webPlayer .controls .leftblock .pause:hover { opacity: 1; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress { position: relative; display: block; margin: 0 130px 0 50px; text-align: left; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress span { font-size: 24px; margin-left: 1px; color: #f0f0f0; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .progressbar { display: none; height: 4px; background-color: #3C3C3C; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); margin: 2.5px 0; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .progressbar .seekBar { position: relative; display: none; cursor: pointer; padding: 1px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .progressbar .seekBar .playBar { display: block; height: 2px; padding: 0; background: #FFFFFF; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .progressbar .seekBar a { display: block; position: absolute; top: -2px; width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 5px; background: #ffffff; margin-left: -3px; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .progressbar .seekBar a div { width: 8px; height: 8px; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .time { display: none; position: absolute; width: 50px; font-size: 11px; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .time.current { left: 1px; text-align: left; color: #f0f0f0; }
.webPlayer .controls .progress .time.duration { right: 0px; text-align: right; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock { position: absolute; right: 10px; width: 110px; top: 5px; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeText { display: block; position: absolute; bottom: -12px; text-align: center; width: 80px; font-size: 11px; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeBar { display: block; position: absolute; height: 4px; background-color: white; width: 80px; top: 19px; left: 0; cursor: pointer; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeBar .currentVolume { position: relative; height: 2px; padding: 1px; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeBar .currentVolume .curvol { display: block; height: 2px; padding: 0; background: #FFFFFF; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeBar .currentVolume a { display: block; position: absolute; top: -2px; margin-left: -3px; width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 5px; background: #ffffff; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .volumeBar .currentVolume a div { display: block; width: 8px; height: 8px; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .fullScreen { display: block; float: right; width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url("playerUI.png") no-repeat 0 -50px; margin-top: 12px; opacity: 0.4; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .fullScreen:hover { opacity: 0.8; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .fullScreenOFF { display: block; float: right; width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url("playerUI.png") no-repeat 0 -68px; margin-top: 12px; opacity: 0.4; }
.webPlayer .controls .rightblock .fullScreenOFF:hover { opacity: 0.8; }
.webPlayer.audioPlayer .progress { margin-right: 100px; }
.webPlayer.audioPlayer .rightblock { width: 85px; }
.webPlayer.audioPlayer .rightblock .volumeText { bottom: -42px; }
.webPlayer.audioPlayer .fullScreen { display: none; }
.webPlayer.audioPlayer .fullScreenOFF { display: none; }
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: I hope you can show us a working demo with the CSS and HTML in a fiddle. `:)`

Comment: Praveen Kumar: What do you mean?

Comment: What do you don't understand?

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RiccardoNL/yrq9mk2d/1/

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I don't understand your #LearnToIndent comment.

Comment: I checked your fiddle, what exactly is your problem? You have too many `position: relative` and `position: absolute` items, that cause overlap in smaller resolutions.

Comment: Were you able to see that your question is edited and now your code is perfectly readable? Before that it was not indented. Do you understand what does indenting the code mean?

Comment: The text in "activebox" dives under the other boxes. The div just doesn't close well, for an unknown reason.

See this picture: http://imgur.com/pu3oVBy. As you can see, all the text in the div activebox is automatically selected. If it would work correctly, only the text would be selected.

Comment: I guessed it. It is because of the improper or unplanned use of absolute positioning. Let's wait for others to answer. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I deleted the WebPlayer part as a test, and it didn't fix it :(.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to only include the Shortest Program Necessary To Reproduce The Issue. See also: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some layout issues in your CSS. Your are declaring heights for `tiles 1-5`, and these are extending beyond the boundaries of their parent container which is `#section1`. Try setting up a height for the `#section1` container as well, such as `410px` to account for the top offset of `10px` from the tiles elements.

```
#section1{
   ...
   height:410px;
   ...
}
```